# format timestamp as string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Timespan variable which should store the resulting subtraction operation from two datetime value and then display them in a dd:hh:mm format.

This is what I have tried so far and it doesn't work

```
Duration=(DateTime.Now- instance.StagesInformations.Last().Value.TransactionDate).ToString("\\hh:mm")
```

Please help

Comment: what you want is the difference of 2 DateTime, right?

Comment: yes Pranav that was I want to achieve

Answer (score 11):

[`TimeSpan` formatting strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx) are somewhat different than `DateTime` formatting strings.  You need to escape literal characters like `:`:

```
.ToString("dd\\:hh\\:mm")
```

or use `@` so you don't have to escape the formatting escape characters:

```
.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm")
```

That said, why not just store as a `TimeSpan` and let the display layer format it? (I'm assuming you're storing in a class property based on your syntax)

Comment: I always recieve "no overload to method ToString takes one argument" with this approach

Comment: With the code you posted?  That's not possible - the result has to be a `TimeSpan`.  If you call `ToString()` on an _object_ you'd get that error, but it should be fine for `TimeSpan`. If you're getting that error somewhere else you need a cast.

Comment: @user989865 [`TimeSpan.ToString(string)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) added with .NET Framework 4.0 version. That might be the reason if you use lower version.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve your desired format `dd:hh:mm` it should be `.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm")`

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference.